# Ubuntu 11.10 got virus or malware, how to delete entire disk and re install?

Tags: 11.10, installation, malware

Had the Ubuntu sitting idle, came back to find it had linked and connected to malware sites, do not know how.  Just want to delete/re install.  want to stay with 11.10

the pc itself does not have a cd-rom drive, the question is how to wipe the disk, and then what about re installing?  from a usb stick?

Comment: ***Practice safe computing:***  Make sure you backup regularly.  Make a separate copy (to a spare USB) of your key documents, music, media, emails - before scrubbing the drive, and re-installing.  Use a **strong password** and **lock screen** when not in use, but also add security (eg. *NoScript*) to your browser and **learn how** to use it properly.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what virus you caught.

Answer (score 0):

Yes from another computer you need to install the Ubuntu ISO to a USB stick. There are special programs used to do this.

Here is a guide to do it from windows if you have one of those near you:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

MacOSX:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Ubuntu:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

If you have another ubuntu machine there should be a USB stick creator in the preferences or the administrator utilities.

If you don't have it you can install it with this:

```
sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk or usb-creator-kde
```

Answer (score 0):

its is very easy to stick with 11.10 and reinstall with a USB stick. There are many options here but my personal favourite is installing 11.10 to your USB drive using UNetbootin (free and easily available) make sure you mark it as executable and have 7zip installed.

All you need to do then is give download the 11.10 .iso from ubuntu.com and point UNetbootin to that .iso and install. Voila, now you can reinstall 11.10

**make sure you backup all your files. If you want to, I would recommend making the new partitions yourself so you can install your /home directory to a different partition to your '/' directory. That way, in future you won't need to wipe your files away when you reinstall.